# Contact is not updated after editing it with CNContactViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactviewcontroller

Recently the testers detected than when a contact is created within the App using **CNContactViewController** and an invalid phone number (for example, 12345) is inserted and the contact is saved.

When they try to edit the contact and update the phone number so it has 10 digits, the contact appears to be saved, but editing it again shows the old number (12345) and also in the Contacts App the contact still has the old number.

When this happens, the CNContactViewControllerDelegate function

```
func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) { }
```

returns contact as **nil**. But with other phone numbers it returns the new values correctly.

After googling a lot and unable to find a solution, I decided to create another viewController that imitates the CNContactViewController but using a **CNMutableContact** and **CNSaveRequest** to update the phone and still the contact doesnt updates.

Note: This only happens when the contact is created with an invalid phone number and then edited. I initialize the viewController like this

```
let controller = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: nil)
```

and then I push it to a navigationController

Comment: After reading lots of docs, I found that the **CNContactStore** recommends to to refetch objects after you fetch them and store any kind of reference to them, do so when the _ CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification_ notification is posted. Although I sill don't know why this behaviour creates strange results, it seems to be "fixed" when refetching all the results or at least only the contact to edit or was edited.